# How to script all the service broker elements for each database it is on, in the current server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, scripting, dmv, service-broker

I have [service broker running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/sql-server-service-broker) on different servers.

Just recently I had to rebuild one of the test servers and it had a complete service broker solution running there.

For the next time I need to rebuild a server that has service broker running in any of its databases

[I would like to script all the service broker architecture for that specific database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40058/generate-script-for-sql-broker-objects/40060#40060)

```
-- Message Types
SELECT * 
FROM sys.service_message_types;
```

[image]

Basically using the scripts below, how can I be able to script all the service broker elements for a particular database?

```
-- Message Types
SELECT * 
FROM sys.service_message_types;

-- Contracts
SELECT * 
FROM sys.service_contracts;

-- Queues
SELECT * 
FROM sys.service_queues;

-- Services
SELECT * 
FROM sys.services;

-- routes
SELECT * 
FROM sys.routes;


-- Endpoints
SELECT * 
FROM sys.endpoints;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing [a recent comment from David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40058/generate-script-for-sql-broker-objects/40060#comment436488_40060):

> SSDT / SqlPackage supports Service Broker objects.

I tried it out. I created some service broker objects based on the demo here:

- [Configuring Service Broker for Asynchronous Processing](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/configuring-service-broker)

Then I download the DAC framework from here:

- [Download Microsoft® SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework (18.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57468)

Then I ran this command (without the carriage returns):

```
sqlpackage 
  /Action:extract 
  /SourceServerName:.\instancename
  /SourceDatabaseName:AsyncProcessingDemo 
  /TargetFile:C:\scripts\sb.dacpac
```

Then I went to `c:\scripts`, right-clicked the dacpac file, and chose **Unpack...**:

> [image]

This asked me for an output folder:

> [image]

I clicked **Unpack**, went to that folder, and there were four files, including `model.xml`:

> [image]

And sure enough, that .sql file contained a script for all the broker objects, assembled in *almost* the right order. It generated a script with the contract created before the message types it depends on. So you will end up with:

```
CREATE CONTRACT ... ([MessageType1] SENT BY INITIATOR, ...
GO
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [MessageType1]...
```

You'll need to flip those around so the message types are created first.

I'm sure SqlPackage.exe and/or the DAC wizard has ways to restrict this to just the service broker objects, but this should be a good start.

Comment: I've downloaded the file, but I could not run the program. what is the exec called? I could not find sqlpackage

Comment: @marcellomiorelli If you've run `DacFramework.msi`, you should be able to find `SqlPackage.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin`.

Answer (score 1):

[Following on the accepted answer by Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/222368/22336)

and then the comments:

If you've run DacFramework.msi, you should be able to find SqlPackage.exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin. – [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)

I run the following command from the location described above (without the carriage returns):

`sqlpackage   /Action:extract /SourceServerName:SQLPROD1 /SourceDatabaseName:COLA /TargetFile:"D:\Service Broker\COLA.dacpac"`

and I got this result:
[image]

after that, opening the generated file, all database objects were scripted, including the service broker ones.